# How to properly update requests in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-requests, apt-get

I am currently using a python package that depends on requests 2.7.0 or greater, but the requests in my system, Ubuntu 14.04, is version 2.2.1. I tried to upgrade via pip:

```
 pip install requests==2.7.0
```

but it gives me an error, saying:

```
Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I tried to upgrade it by using `apt-get install --only-upgrade python-requests`, but it says that it is already on the latest version (and it's not).

Then I tried to install in a virtual env, but it gives the same message as the pip message above.

Finally, I thought about two options:

1-) Uninstalling via apt-get and then installing via pip - I think it's too risky, since it will uninstall a lot of other packages.

2-) Cloning from github and manually installing via setup.py, but I also fear that it may mess with other packages depending on it

What is the best way to do it? Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: Could you give us your pip command because I can do a mkvirtualenv foo then pip install requests witout any problem and it installs requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl. Maybe you can uninstall the debian package before pip

Comment: Did you install requests with `sudo` initially? I've found that a lot of `pip` errors are caused by installing something somewhere that `sudo` can access it, but that a normal user cannot.

Comment: Edited with pip command. What is the difference between virtualenv foo and mkvirtualenv foo?

Comment: Try `pip install --update requests`?

Comment: @wilbur, I think python-requests came with the system.

Comment: mkvirtualenv (and the related tools) allow the virtual env-related files to be stored in a common place, and generally they help you to manage a lot of virtual envs without going crazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
~ › sudo apt-get install -u python-requests
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-requests is already the newest version.
python-requests set to manually installed.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 15 not to upgrade.

~ › python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.0.1'
>>> 

~ › mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

~ (test) › pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests-2.9.1

~ (test) › python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.9.1'
>>>
```

I wonder why your OS/Ubuntu version of requests is 2.2.1, whereas mine is 2.0.1. Have you installed a newer version of requests manually, via some other mechanism than the official python-requests .deb package? As suggested by @wilbur in the comments above, is it possible you have run `sudo pip install requests` at some point in the past? If so, it might be worth running `sudo pip uninstall requests` to see if you can get rid of it...

Comment: It worked in virtualenv. I was using pip with sudo inside virtualenv, and so it was using system wide pip, not the virtualenv one. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

I needed requests >2.10.0 for socks proxy built-in support.
Force uninstall
`dpkg --remove --force-depends python-requests` breaks apt (even if requests is pip installed).

`apt-get install python-requests` rolls it back to 2.2.1, the maximum version in **trusty** repo.
However, **yakkety** ubuntu repo contains 2.10.0 python-requests, as needed, so i did the following:

```
 apt-add-repository "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main"
 apt-get update
 apt-get install python-requests # it installs 2.10.0
 apt-add-repository -r "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main"
 apt-get update
```

*Note!* It is essential to do the second `apt-get update` to remove yakkety index not to execute `apt-get upgrade` occasionally and break your system.

So now I have the required version.

```
$ sudo pip2 show requests
    ---
    Name: requests
    Version: 2.10.0
    Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
    Requires:
```

Comment: This is system-wide solution. If you need virtualenv one, see previous answers